# How to put duration in firestore flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing a school project for ecommerce app in flutter.

I need to save the "DURATION" of preparation of the food in my app and retrieve it from firestore. Do i need to save it as a timestamp? If so, how would i retrieve it and convert it again to duration so it would show how many minutes or hours the food preparation is?

here is a sample of my code:

```
class ProductModel { 
  String? productName; 
  String? prdouctImgUrl; 
  double? productPrice; 
  // Duration? preparationTime; ===> the preparation time of the food
  
  ProductModel();
  ProductModel.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snap){
  productName = snap["productName"];
  prdouctImgUrl= snap["prdouctImgUrl"];
  productPrice= snap["productPrice"];
  //preparationTime= snap["preparationTime"]; 
  }

  }

  //showing of products
  .....
  _product = ProductModel.fromSnapshot(snapshot.data!.docs[i]);
  return ListTile(
  leading: CircleAvatar(
  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(_product.prdouctImgUrl),
  child: _product.prdouctImgUrl.isEmpty
  ? Text("${_product.productName[0].toUpperCase()}") : SizedBox(),
  radius: 15,),
  title: Text(_product.productName),
  //subtitle: Text("Preparation time ${_product.preparationTime]} \n Expected delivery date: ${DateTime.now().add(_product.preparationTime])}"), 
  //  I want to show how many minutes the preparation time is and when can the customer receive the items

)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [intl package](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) to format datetimes as you please.

For example:

```
var timeHourMinute = DateFormat('H:m').format(DateTime.now()); // 12:30
var timeMinute = DateFormat('m').format(DateTime.now()); // 30
```